# Python - matching on nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I've got the following code;

```
#!/usr/bin/python

list1 = [[1,1,1,2], 2, [1,2,3,6], 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1,1, [6,7], 7, 14 , 8, 9]
list3 = []


def check_match(l1,l2):
    for i in l1:
        if type(i) is list:
            check_match(i,l2)
        for j in l2:
            if type(j) is list:
                check_match(l1,j)
            else:
                if i == j:
                    list3.append(i)

print(list3)
```

The above code returns an empty list []

Essentially, what i'm trying to do is create a 3rd list which will contain only the unique values, which should look like this;

list3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,14]

If anyone can guide me, that would be great.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
list1 = [[1,1,1,2], 2, [1,2,3,6], 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1,1, [6,7], 7, 14 , 8, 9]


no_dub=[]
def checker(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in lst:
            if isinstance(i,list):
                for k in i:
                    if k not in no_dub:
                        no_dub.append(k)

            else:
                if i not in no_dub:
                    no_dub.append(i)

            return checker(lst[1:])

checker(list1)
checker(list2)
print(no_dub)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 14, 8, 9]
```

If you don't want to pass one by one then :

```
check_all=[list1,list2]
for i in check_all:
    checker(i)

print(no_dub)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 7, 14, 8, 9]
```

Update as per request :

```
list1 = [[1,1,1,2], 2, [1,2,3,6], 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1,1, [6,7], 7, 14 , 8, 9]


no_dub=[]
def checker(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 0
    else:
        for i in lst:
            if isinstance(i,list):
                for k in i:
                    if "ID{}".format(k) not in no_dub:
                        no_dub.append("ID{}".format(k))

            else:
                if "ID{}".format(i) not in no_dub:
                    no_dub.append("ID{}".format(i))

            return checker(lst[1:])

check_all=[list1,list2]
for i in check_all:
    checker(i)

print(no_dub)
```

output:

```
['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID6', 'ID4', 'ID5', 'ID7', 'ID14', 'ID8', 'ID9']
```

Comment: once last request, what's the best way to append a string before the value of i so that the output reads;

[ID1, ID2, ID3, ID6, ID4, ID5, ID7, ID14, ID8, ID9]

Thanks mate

Comment: @ik_tech check the updated solution , I have edited the answer.

Comment: @ik_tech Or once you get the list3, you can do `['ID'+str(e) for e in list3]`. This will merge ID in front of each element in the list.

Comment: @FatihAkici why additional loop when we can do this via same loop ?

Comment: thanks guys - any benefit of the flattening as opposed to the solution posted by Aydohyankit?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul isn't it less complex to flatten out in one loop, and then append 'ID's in a separate loop, rather than calling the checker function in a loop, which contains another loop, therefore a nested loop?

Comment: @FatihAkici where i am calling checker seprate for append only 'ID' ? nested loop is for nested list , I am doing all things in same iteration where you are using another loop which will iterate again over all result values just to add 'ID'

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul What I am asking is a n+n vs n*n comparison. Say list1+list2 has n elements. Your solution calls `checker(i)` n times, and checker itself has a loop of `for i in lst`, and yet another nested loop of `for k in i`. But my solution has only 1 loop of size n (please see below) of `for e in l` and then the `['ID'+str(e) for e in list3]` separately. My question is which one is more efficient?

Comment: @FatihAkici list(set(flatList)) is also an iterator my friend. so if you have one loop `for e in l:`  and then `list(set(flatList))` and then `['ID'+str(e) for e in list3]`  , Now you have three iterators.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using recursion to flatten your lists and then using a set:

```
def flatten(s, target=int): 
   if type(s) == target:
       yield s
   else:
      for i in s:
         for b in flatten(i):
            yield b

list1 = [[1,1,1,2], 2, [1,2,3,6], 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1,1, [6,7], 7, 14 , 8, 9]
final_result = list(set([*list(flatten(list1)), *list(flatten(list2))]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to make flat list out of `list1` and `list2`, make an extended list which contains both elements of `list1` and `list2` and cast the resulting list to set to remove duplicate elements.

Solution i am giving is little less verbose and involve less number of lines

```
#Flatten list function
flatten=lambda l: sum(map(flatten,l),[]) if isinstance(l,list) else [l]
list1 = flatten(list1) #[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = flatten(list2) #[1, 1, 6, 7, 7, 14, 8, 9]
list1.extend(list2) #[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 6, 7, 7, 14, 8, 9]
list(set(list1))
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that flattens a list, and then convert the result to a `set()`:

```
list1 = [[1,1,1,2], 2, [1,2,3,6], 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1,1, [6,7], 7, 14 , 8, 9]

def flatten(lst):
    flattened = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            flattened.extend(flatten(item))
        else:
            flattened.append(item)

    return flattened

print(sorted(list(set(flatten(list1 + list2)))))
```

Which Outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest flattening and then using set, but saw almost identical answers when I finished coding. Nevertheless, this is how I would do it:

```
list1 = [[1,1,1,2], 2, [1,2,3,6], 3, 4, 5]
list2 = [1,1, [6,7], 7, 14 , 8, 9]
l = list1+list2
flatList = []
for e in l:
    if type(e) == list:
        flatList.extend(e)
    else:
        flatList.append(e)
list(set(flatList))
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14]
```